# Play and stop audio on :hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm creating an e-commerce website, and I've encountered a problem that I can't solve.

I have 3 boxes on one of the pages where there's a photo in each box, and when you hover over it, the photo disappears and a video appears.

The issue is that I can't make the sound play when the video is shown, and stop it when I move away from the box with the mouse. This is because if I don't apply the 'muted' property in the video tag, it doesn't work in some browsers.

I've added the audio separately, and sometimes it works, but not always.

I'm still a newbie, so your help would be great to keep learning and be able to solve this. I'm using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (GSAP). Thanks a lot in advance!

```html
<div id="page2-elements">
  <div class="box" onmouseover="playMedia(this)" onmouseout="pauseMedia(this)">
    <a href="/shop" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-2"></a>
    <img src="./assets/box1_img.png" alt="" />
    <video muted loop src="./assets/box1.mp4"></video>
    <audio>
      <source src="./assets/box1.mp3" type="audio" />
    </audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function playMedia(element) {
  var video = element.querySelector("video");
  var audio = element.querySelector("audio");
  if (video) {
    video.play();
  }
  if (audio) {
    audio.play();
  }
}

function pauseMedia(element) {
  var video = element.querySelector("video");
  var audio = element.querySelector("audio");
  if (video) {
    video.pause();
  }
  if (audio) {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's likely the issue with playing unmuted video is because the user has to 'interact' with the page first, and exactly what counts as interaction depends on the browser. Normally, clicking a button or image to trigger video playback is enough, but simply hovering is not. You can confirm this by checking in the console for messages notifying you that the video playback was limited. If this is the problem, then it can easily be fixed by using click events instead of hover.

Comment: Modern browser expect a "user interaction", that indicates the user actually _wanted_ to play a video with sounds. Such an interaction usually is an explicit _click_ on something to trigger playing the video. If just hovering could be used to achieve the same, then many of the "bad" people who made these restrictions necessary in the first place, would use the same technique, to _still_ get their videos blaring sounds, in situations where users did _not_ want this.

Comment: Hovering is not an expression of any specific intention at all. People will do that when they are initially "exploring" a site, or they might simply move the mouse cursor because they want to read a piece of text else on the page without distraction by the cursor hovering over it. You starting to autoplay a video with sound in that situation, would _add_ distraction. So don't look for any "workarounds" here, but - fix the _concept_ instead. Play videos when users clearly signaled their intention by explicitly clicking on something, that makes it _clear_ a video will play as the result.

Comment: I leave the link to see what my idea was (scroll down to page 2) https://unrivaled-sunflower-dbb222.netlify.app/

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I thought that displaying a video of the product when hovering over its photo without having to click would be a good idea, but I guess I was wrong. Thanks again, I'll keep working on it